# R - lubridate: split durations into "sub-durations"

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a R tidy dataset `my_durations` where each case in the data frame corresponds to a sample taken over a duration of time like so:

```
> glimpse(my_durations)
Observations: 300
Variables: 5
$ sample_id  <int> 2, 8, 25, 41, 59, 70, 98, 100, 105, 106, 108, 114, 119, 126,...
$ site_id    <int> 2, 13, 12, 23, 47, 23, 66, 72, 72, 50, 50, 54, 45, 73, 48, 7...
$ start_date <dttm> 2015-04-12, 2015-06-10, 2015-07-02, 2015-07-22, 2015-07-29,...
$ end_date   <dttm> 2015-05-14, 2015-06-18, 2015-07-08, 2015-07-24, 2015-07-30,...
$ duration   <time> 32 days, 8 days, 6 days, 2 days, 1 days, 4 days, 12 days, 2...
```

Where `sample_id` is the unique ID for that sample, `site_id` is just an ID for keeping track of where the sample was taken, `start_date` and `end_date` are when the sampling began and ended, and `duration` is simply the difference in time between `start_date` and `end_date`.

Here is the full `dput()` for the dataset:

```
structure(list(sample_id = c(2L, 8L, 25L, 41L, 59L, 70L, 98L, 
100L, 105L, 106L, 108L, 114L, 119L, 126L, 128L, 146L, 151L, 164L, 
167L, 169L, 175L, 190L, 198L, 200L, 222L, 237L, 254L, 273L, 276L, 
280L, 281L, 290L, 300L, 305L, 314L, 345L, 354L, 371L, 376L, 379L, 
380L, 382L, 383L, 389L, 401L, 410L, 413L, 424L, 439L, 466L, 469L, 
476L, 482L, 484L, 499L, 505L, 517L, 538L, 580L, 582L, 583L, 584L, 
635L, 650L, 655L, 658L, 662L, 671L, 674L, 702L, 709L, 710L, 712L, 
715L, 716L, 724L, 734L, 735L, 738L, 785L, 789L, 793L, 794L, 803L, 
833L, 856L, 859L, 865L, 866L, 888L, 895L, 898L, 900L, 907L, 938L, 
979L, 980L, 988L, 991L, 1009L, 1026L, 1031L, 1034L, 1050L, 1058L, 
1061L, 1063L, 1066L, 1069L, 1077L, 1081L, 1091L, 1092L, 1099L, 
1100L, 1108L, 1115L, 1119L, 1143L, 1149L, 1158L, 1180L, 1190L, 
1195L, 1198L, 1207L, 1231L, 1234L, 1236L, 1242L, 1249L, 1250L, 
1271L, 1288L, 1294L, 1311L, 1312L, 1313L, 1319L, 1337L, 1341L, 
1345L, 1349L, 1360L, 1374L, 1379L, 1389L, 1393L, 1396L, 1401L, 
1404L, 1407L, 1422L, 1434L, 1438L, 1448L, 1454L, 1463L, 1473L, 
1489L, 1508L, 1514L, 1518L, 1531L, 1551L, 1564L, 1565L, 1571L, 
1572L, 1597L, 1602L, 1619L, 1624L, 1629L, 1630L, 1659L, 1661L, 
1666L, 1669L, 1672L, 1678L, 1690L, 1697L, 1700L, 1703L, 1707L, 
1715L, 1719L, 1725L, 1732L, 1737L, 1739L, 1754L, 1771L, 1788L, 
1790L, 1796L, 1799L, 1802L, 1805L, 1813L, 1814L, 1832L, 1839L, 
1844L, 1848L, 1873L, 1887L, 1893L, 1900L, 1901L, 1917L, 1920L, 
1939L, 1948L, 1954L, 1956L, 1968L, 1971L, 1975L, 1979L, 2008L, 
2015L, 2019L, 2021L, 2028L, 2035L, 2048L, 2062L, 2071L, 2072L, 
2075L, 2085L, 2090L, 2091L, 2100L, 2106L, 2115L, 2172L, 2178L, 
2181L, 2221L, 2225L, 2228L, 2230L, 2231L, 2237L, 2241L, 2265L, 
2266L, 2271L, 2282L, 2284L, 2311L, 2319L, 2337L, 2377L, 2405L, 
2409L, 2412L, 2429L, 2434L, 2460L, 2483L, 2485L, 2488L, 2490L, 
2500L, 2513L, 2520L, 2521L, 2527L, 2539L, 2555L, 2569L, 2599L, 
2605L, 2610L, 2635L, 2640L, 2641L, 2656L, 2667L, 2689L, 2705L, 
2720L, 2747L, 2753L, 2756L, 2761L, 2769L, 2772L, 2809L, 2816L, 
2818L, 2821L, 2823L, 2828L, 2837L, 2838L), site_id = c(2L, 13L, 
12L, 23L, 47L, 23L, 66L, 72L, 72L, 50L, 50L, 54L, 45L, 73L, 48L, 
73L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 52L, 66L, 73L, 76L, 95L, 61L, 73L, 106L, 
72L, 108L, 90L, 91L, 44L, 103L, 90L, 108L, 105L, 122L, 131L, 
133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 52L, 138L, 136L, 113L, 146L, 55L, 
147L, 113L, 151L, 147L, 117L, 74L, 160L, 55L, 73L, 74L, 73L, 
151L, 73L, 169L, 168L, 73L, 73L, 44L, 73L, 182L, 74L, 73L, 105L, 
160L, 184L, 184L, 74L, 74L, 73L, 113L, 199L, 73L, 202L, 198L, 
73L, 199L, 74L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 198L, 213L, 212L, 213L, 44L, 160L, 
221L, 218L, 230L, 226L, 201L, 74L, 73L, 230L, 184L, 161L, 74L, 
74L, 73L, 214L, 74L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 73L, 74L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 
226L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 201L, 201L, 73L, 74L, 242L, 226L, 74L, 74L, 
113L, 73L, 249L, 73L, 249L, 74L, 247L, 240L, 73L, 74L, 44L, 73L, 
201L, 74L, 74L, 191L, 73L, 254L, 201L, 248L, 237L, 260L, 73L, 
226L, 74L, 191L, 226L, 259L, 73L, 226L, 74L, 237L, 74L, 248L, 
275L, 276L, 276L, 277L, 277L, 260L, 280L, 280L, 160L, 244L, 262L, 
74L, 44L, 74L, 44L, 73L, 74L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 73L, 74L, 73L, 
244L, 74L, 73L, 105L, 74L, 74L, 294L, 73L, 223L, 223L, 248L, 
295L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 295L, 73L, 269L, 73L, 201L, 199L, 74L, 74L, 
74L, 271L, 292L, 105L, 292L, 199L, 267L, 292L, 305L, 74L, 74L, 
295L, 309L, 74L, 310L, 310L, 271L, 316L, 74L, 73L, 305L, 73L, 
113L, 74L, 74L, 73L, 191L, 74L, 245L, 226L, 321L, 241L, 320L, 
113L, 323L, 73L, 320L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 73L, 73L, 191L, 74L, 73L, 
74L, 74L, 74L, 73L, 245L, 113L, 73L, 16L, 73L, 348L, 350L, 245L, 
306L, 191L, 245L, 350L, 244L, 348L, 113L, 191L, 306L, 73L, 73L, 
306L, 350L, 73L, 361L, 245L, 73L, 114L, 191L, 73L, 357L, 361L, 
376L, 364L, 360L, 378L, 357L, 73L, 380L, 73L, 350L, 364L), start_date = structure(c(1428796800, 
1433894400, 1435795200, 1437523200, 1438128000, 1438300800, 1437609600, 
1438905600, 1438905600, 1438041600, 1438041600, 1438646400, 1438560000, 
1439424000, 1438819200, 1440115200, 1439856000, 1440115200, 1440115200, 
1438041600, 1440460800, 1441497600, 1440547200, 1441238400, 1438992000, 
1442707200, 1443225600, 1439337600, 1440633600, 1442707200, 1442707200, 
1444089600, 1442534400, 1444348800, 1443225600, 1444694400, 1445817600, 
1445472000, 1446854400, 1446854400, 1446854400, 1446854400, 1446854400, 
1441584000, 1447459200, 1447372800, 1444348800, 1447977600, 1448064000, 
1448064000, 1446940800, 1449014400, 1448064000, 1445904000, 1449878400, 
1449792000, 1449878400, 1451001600, 1452729600, 1452902400, 1452470400, 
1452988800, 1453075200, 1454889600, 1455235200, 1455408000, 1454976000, 
1455753600, 1453766400, 1456963200, 1457308800, 1456876800, 1456876800, 
1456790400, 1457395200, 1457827200, 1458086400, 1458172800, 1455580800, 
1460073600, 1460419200, 1456617600, 1460073600, 1460851200, 1460073600, 
1462233600, 1462320000, 1462492800, 1462665600, 1460073600, 1462579200, 
1462492800, 1462579200, 1462838400, 1463443200, 1463702400, 1463616000, 
1464912000, 1464825600, 1465171200, 1466035200, 1466121600, 1464912000, 
1461888000, 1464652800, 1466467200, 1466553600, 1466640000, 1462579200, 
1466726400, 1466985600, 1467331200, 1467331200, 1467590400, 1467590400, 
1467936000, 1468108800, 1468281600, 1468368000, 1469145600, 1469404800, 
1470009600, 1470009600, 1470009600, 1470441600, 1470787200, 1471219200, 
1470096000, 1470268800, 1470873600, 1467590400, 1471564800, 1471478400, 
1472256000, 1471478400, 1472515200, 1471219200, 1472256000, 1472601600, 
1472860800, 1472688000, 1473292800, 1472947200, 1473638400, 1474243200, 
1474156800, 1475193600, 1475193600, 1474761600, 1475193600, 1471046400, 
1475193600, 1476316800, 1473724800, 1476748800, 1476403200, 1476748800, 
1477785600, 1478044800, 1477958400, 1479168000, 1478304000, 1479254400, 
1473811200, 1477699200, 1476576000, 1476576000, 1477872000, 1478476800, 
1475193600, 1477094400, 1477094400, 1479859200, 1479340800, 1475884800, 
1480896000, 1480464000, 1480982400, 1480982400, 1481241600, 1481846400, 
1482192000, 1482451200, 1482537600, 1482624000, 1482969600, 1483228800, 
1483401600, 1481846400, 1483747200, 1483920000, 1483488000, 1484438400, 
1484956800, 1485216000, 1485388800, 1473292800, 1478995200, 1485216000, 
1485216000, 1485907200, 1485907200, 1486339200, 1485216000, 1486512000, 
1485216000, 1487116800, 1487030400, 1485388800, 1487721600, 1487808000, 
1488153600, 1487289600, 1485129600, 1488240000, 1485129600, 1485388800, 
1480896000, 1485129600, 1488412800, 1489104000, 1490054400, 1485216000, 
1490054400, 1490400000, 1490572800, 1490659200, 1489622400, 1489881600, 
1491436800, 1491523200, 1488412800, 1491782400, 1488758400, 1491868800, 
1492473600, 1492646400, 1492387200, 1494633600, 1494288000, 1494288000, 
1495152000, 1494201600, 1494979200, 1491868800, 1495065600, 1496102400, 
1494979200, 1497052800, 1497052800, 1497225600, 1497657600, 1497744000, 
1498435200, 1499212800, 1499904000, 1501372800, 1502409600, 1502582400, 
1502668800, 1502236800, 1501718400, 1504569600, 1502841600, 1505174400, 
1503878400, 1503964800, 1505260800, 1503964800, 1505606400, 1505865600, 
1503964800, 1504656000, 1503878400, 1505520000, 1508716800, 1503964800, 
1509580800, 1510704000, 1503964800, 1503964800, 1511481600, 1508889600, 
1512518400, 1513987200, 1513555200, 1514764800, 1516665600, 1515456000, 
1508889600, 1517097600, 1511654400, 1510012800, 1518393600, 1515456000, 
1519257600, 1518825600, 1519344000, 1503964800, 1511654400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), end_date = structure(c(1431561600, 
1434585600, 1436313600, 1437696000, 1438214400, 1438646400, 1438646400, 
1439078400, 1439078400, 1438128000, 1438128000, 1439164800, 1438905600, 
1439942400, 1438992000, 1440288000, 1440460800, 1440720000, 1440720000, 
1438128000, 1440547200, 1441584000, 1441238400, 1441670400, 1439769600, 
1443052800, 1444003200, 1439769600, 1441324800, 1444348800, 1444348800, 
1444694400, 1444521600, 1444867200, 1445126400, 1445212800, 1446336000, 
1445558400, 1447113600, 1447286400, 1447372800, 1447545600, 1447632000, 
1442707200, 1447545600, 1448236800, 1444608000, 1448236800, 1449014400, 
1449273600, 1449273600, 1449532800, 1449446400, 1445990400, 1450051200, 
1450137600, 1450396800, 1451174400, 1452902400, 1452988800, 1453075200, 
1453075200, 1454716800, 1455148800, 1455321600, 1455494400, 1455580800, 
1455840000, 1454976000, 1457049600, 1457395200, 1457395200, 1457395200, 
1457395200, 1457481600, 1457913600, 1458172800, 1458345600, 1458518400, 
1460419200, 1460592000, 1457222400, 1460592000, 1460937600, 1461801600, 
1462320000, 1462406400, 1462665600, 1462752000, 1462924800, 1462924800, 
1463097600, 1463270400, 1463443200, 1464134400, 1464912000, 1464912000, 
1465084800, 1465257600, 1465776000, 1466121600, 1466208000, 1466208000, 
1463702400, 1466553600, 1466553600, 1466640000, 1466726400, 1466726400, 
1466812800, 1467072000, 1467417600, 1467417600, 1467676800, 1467676800, 
1468022400, 1468195200, 1468368000, 1468972800, 1469232000, 1469491200, 
1470096000, 1470614400, 1470614400, 1470528000, 1470873600, 1471305600, 
1471305600, 1470355200, 1471219200, 1471564800, 1471651200, 1471910400, 
1472342400, 1472083200, 1472601600, 1472601600, 1472601600, 1472688000, 
1473120000, 1473206400, 1473379200, 1473638400, 1473811200, 1474502400, 
1474761600, 1475280000, 1475366400, 1475452800, 1475712000, 1472515200, 
1475884800, 1476403200, 1475625600, 1476835200, 1477180800, 1477440000, 
1477872000, 1478131200, 1478649600, 1479254400, 1479513600, 1479600000, 
1476316800, 1478476800, 1477526400, 1477699200, 1478304000, 1478649600, 
1476576000, 1477699200, 1480204800, 1480464000, 1480636800, 1476403200, 
1480982400, 1480982400, 1481241600, 1481587200, 1481673600, 1481932800, 
1482278400, 1482537600, 1482624000, 1482796800, 1483056000, 1483315200, 
1483488000, 1483660800, 1483833600, 1484006400, 1484006400, 1484524800, 
1485043200, 1485388800, 1485475200, 1474761600, 1480809600, 1485734400, 
1485734400, 1485993600, 1485993600, 1486425600, 1486425600, 1486598400, 
1486684800, 1487203200, 1487462400, 1487635200, 1487808000, 1487894400, 
1488240000, 1488240000, 1488672000, 1488844800, 1488931200, 1488931200, 
1485648000, 1489449600, 1489449600, 1489536000, 1490140800, 1490313600, 
1490400000, 1490572800, 1490659200, 1490745600, 1491004800, 1489968000, 
1491523200, 1491609600, 1491609600, 1491868800, 1491868800, 1492128000, 
1492560000, 1492732800, 1492992000, 1494720000, 1494892800, 1494979200, 
1495670400, 1495843200, 1495670400, 1495929600, 1495324800, 1496188800, 
1496188800, 1497139200, 1497139200, 1497312000, 1497744000, 1497830400, 
1498953600, 1499299200, 1499990400, 1501459200, 1502496000, 1502668800, 
1502755200, 1503446400, 1503446400, 1504656000, 1503100800, 1505260800, 
1505260800, 1505260800, 1505865600, 1506211200, 1506297600, 1506470400, 
1506470400, 1507075200, 1507248000, 1508025600, 1509235200, 1509321600, 
1509753600, 1510790400, 1510790400, 1510790400, 1511568000, 1511913600, 
1513123200, 1514160000, 1514764800, 1516320000, 1516752000, 1516838400, 
1516838400, 1517184000, 1517270400, 1518480000, 1518998400, 1519171200, 
1519344000, 1519344000, 1519430400, 1519689600, 1519689600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), duration = structure(c(32, 8, 6, 2, 
1, 4, 12, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 4, 6, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 8, 5, 
9, 4, 9, 5, 8, 19, 19, 7, 23, 6, 22, 6, 6, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 
13, 1, 10, 3, 3, 11, 14, 27, 6, 16, 1, 2, 4, 6, 2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 
19, 3, 1, 1, 7, 1, 14, 1, 1, 6, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 34, 4, 2, 7, 
6, 1, 20, 1, 1, 2, 1, 33, 4, 7, 8, 7, 8, 14, 15, 2, 5, 7, 1, 
1, 15, 21, 22, 1, 1, 1, 48, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 
1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 4, 46, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 16, 4, 1, 3, 
6, 1, 8, 2, 3, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6, 17, 8, 1, 22, 1, 9, 8, 1, 1, 8, 
1, 14, 4, 29, 9, 11, 13, 5, 2, 16, 7, 36, 7, 15, 6, 1, 6, 3, 
7, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 21, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 17, 21, 
6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 17, 1, 5, 26, 1, 1, 1, 11, 41, 7, 44, 41, 
55, 50, 12, 5, 1, 59, 4, 2, 1, 1, 16, 1, 1, 1, 37, 1, 36, 3, 
1, 1, 7, 1, 7, 8, 6, 19, 8, 47, 3, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 20, 1, 3, 1, 16, 15, 7, 26, 8, 7, 29, 28, 
39, 29, 6, 62, 2, 1, 79, 79, 1, 35, 7, 2, 14, 18, 1, 16, 92, 
1, 65, 98, 7, 43, 1, 6, 1, 182, 93), class = "difftime", units = "days")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -300L))
```

The challenge I am facing now is that for any `duration` that's more than `n` days (let's go with `n == 7` for now), I want to "split" that duration into `n`-day long segments. For example, for `sample_id == 2`, the `duration` is 32 days, so I want to split that into four 7-day segments, plus one 4-day segment. In the end, the original row for `sample_id == 2` would turn into *five* rows each with `start_date`,  `end_date`, and `duration` that correspond to each of the five segments. I would like to have a new column called `segment_id` to identify each of the newly-created segments while keeping all of the original columns. BTW, for the `sample_id`s that have original `duration`s shorter than `n`, I want to keep them as is, and they would get `segment_id == 1`.

I am stumped. Is there a fairly "tidy" way to achieve this? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create columns of lists and `unnest` them:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>% group_by(sample_id,site_id) %>% 
  mutate(duration_new = (as.numeric(duration)-1) %>% seq(0,.,by=7) %>% c(duration) %>% diff %>% list,
         start_date_new = list(start_date + days(c(0,cumsum(head(duration_new[[1]],-1))))),
         end_date_new = list(start_date + days(cumsum(duration_new[[1]]))),
         segment_id = list(seq_along(duration_new[[1]]))) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  ungroup
# # A tibble: 619 x 9
#    sample_id site_id start_date          end_date            duration duration_new start_date_new      end_date_new        segment_id
#        <int>   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <time>          <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>                   <int>
#  1         2       2 2015-04-12 00:00:00 2015-05-14 00:00:00 32                  7 2015-04-12 00:00:00 2015-04-19 00:00:00          1
#  2         2       2 2015-04-12 00:00:00 2015-05-14 00:00:00 32                  7 2015-04-19 00:00:00 2015-04-26 00:00:00          2
#  3         2       2 2015-04-12 00:00:00 2015-05-14 00:00:00 32                  7 2015-04-26 00:00:00 2015-05-03 00:00:00          3
#  4         2       2 2015-04-12 00:00:00 2015-05-14 00:00:00 32                  7 2015-05-03 00:00:00 2015-05-10 00:00:00          4
#  5         2       2 2015-04-12 00:00:00 2015-05-14 00:00:00 32                  4 2015-05-10 00:00:00 2015-05-14 00:00:00          5
#  6         8      13 2015-06-10 00:00:00 2015-06-18 00:00:00 8                   7 2015-06-10 00:00:00 2015-06-17 00:00:00          1
#  7         8      13 2015-06-10 00:00:00 2015-06-18 00:00:00 8                   1 2015-06-17 00:00:00 2015-06-18 00:00:00          2
#  8        25      12 2015-07-02 00:00:00 2015-07-08 00:00:00 6                   6 2015-07-02 00:00:00 2015-07-08 00:00:00          1
#  9        41      23 2015-07-22 00:00:00 2015-07-24 00:00:00 2                   2 2015-07-22 00:00:00 2015-07-24 00:00:00          1
# 10        59      47 2015-07-29 00:00:00 2015-07-30 00:00:00 1                   1 2015-07-29 00:00:00 2015-07-30 00:00:00          1
# # ... with 609 more rows
```

**How the unnesting works**

After the `mutate` call, the `data.frame` has just the same amount of rows as before, but it has new columns. These new columns all contain list elements (elements that are lists), we call them list columns.

Then `unnest` develop these lists vertically and we get our additional rows, elements from columns that were not list columns are just repeated.

from `?unnest` : If you have a list-column, this makes each element of the list its own row.

**how `duration_new` is built**

We a simple sequence of breaks using `seq` (see `?seq`), seq doesn't give the last element however (which is the complete duration), so we add it with `c`. The `diff` of breaks gives the individual durations.

You can execute this step by step (select until before a pipe, ctrl+enter):

```
duration <- 32
(as.numeric(duration)-1) %>% seq(0,.,by=7) %>% c(duration) %>% diff %>% list
```

**how `start_date_new` and `end_date_new` are built**

We start from start_date and add the cumulated durations, for `start_date_new` we add `0` to the first element, so we keep them offset.

Comment: Thank you @Moody_Mudskipper! I just tried this but got the same error as when I tried the other proposed solution: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'." What does that mean??

Comment: did you get this, after restarting your session, on the sample data you gave, and after loading both lubridate and tidyverse ?

Comment: OK, this is bizarre, but after lots of trying I discovered that all I have to do is

Comment: OK, this is bizarre, but after lots of trying I discovered that all I have to do is `rename()` the columns in the data frame to some other names, then `rename()` them back, afterwards your code runs fine! I don't see why this would change anything, do you have a guess as to what happens during this seemingly arbitrary and useless operation??? Anyway, thank you so much for the answer! The thing is I am having trouble understanding what it really does, especially the "nested list" thing which I've never heard of. Can you what the `mutate` line actually does since I'd like to learn? :)

Comment: I can't have a guess if you don't answer my questions ;). I'll detail a bit my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, to answer your question: Yes I did restart my session, reload the libraries and data. Just not sure why I get that error unless I do the `rename`s first... But thanks for your additional explanations!!

Comment: This could be a version issue (updateR and relevant packages), or maybe you're loading other packages (in your Rprofile maybe ? => never do that), or maybe you didn't copy data from your question here, but took yours, and assumed it should be the same and it's not. That's all I can think of. Also, when you restart your session, if it reloads a workspace, it doesn't count, try on a clean session, with `search()` showing only the default packages, and `ls()` showing nothing at all.

Comment: OK, I'll check. But at least in the meantime the strange `rename()` workaround works! Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for not using `dplyr` and `tidyr` but I am much more fluent in `data.table` syntax:

```
n <- 7L
library(data.table)
setDT(my_durations)[, {
  tmp <- unique(c(seq(as.Date(start_date), as.Date(end_date), by = paste(n, "days")), 
                  as.Date(end_date)))
  .(segment_id = head(seq_along(tmp), -1L), 
    segment_start = head(tmp, -1L), 
    segment_end = tail(tmp, -1L),
    segment_duration = diff(tmp))
}, by = .(sample_id, site_id, start_date, end_date, duration)]
```

> ```
>      sample_id site_id start_date   end_date duration segment_id segment_start segment_end segment_duration
>   1:         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14  32 days          1    2015-04-12  2015-04-19           7 days
>   2:         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14  32 days          2    2015-04-19  2015-04-26           7 days
>   3:         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14  32 days          3    2015-04-26  2015-05-03           7 days
>   4:         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14  32 days          4    2015-05-03  2015-05-10           7 days
>   5:         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14  32 days          5    2015-05-10  2015-05-14           4 days
>  ---                                                                                                       
> 615:      2838     364 2017-11-26 2018-02-27  93 days         10    2018-01-28  2018-02-04           7 days
> 616:      2838     364 2017-11-26 2018-02-27  93 days         11    2018-02-04  2018-02-11           7 days
> 617:      2838     364 2017-11-26 2018-02-27  93 days         12    2018-02-11  2018-02-18           7 days
> 618:      2838     364 2017-11-26 2018-02-27  93 days         13    2018-02-18  2018-02-25           7 days
> 619:      2838     364 2017-11-26 2018-02-27  93 days         14    2018-02-25  2018-02-27           2 days
> ```

---

The OP has requested that segments whose duration is shorter than `n` should be kept as is with `segment_id == 1`. This can be verified for the given dataset with `n <- 50L` where above code returns

> ```
>      sample_id site_id start_date   end_date duration segment_id segment_start segment_end segment_duration
>   1:         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14  32 days          1    2015-04-12  2015-05-14          32 days
>   2:         8      13 2015-06-10 2015-06-18   8 days          1    2015-06-10  2015-06-18           8 days
>   3:        25      12 2015-07-02 2015-07-08   6 days          1    2015-07-02  2015-07-08           6 days
>   4:        41      23 2015-07-22 2015-07-24   2 days          1    2015-07-22  2015-07-24           2 days
>   5:        59      47 2015-07-29 2015-07-30   1 days          1    2015-07-29  2015-07-30           1 days
>  ---                                                                                                       
> 308:      2837     350 2017-08-29 2018-02-27 182 days          2    2017-10-18  2017-12-07          50 days
> 309:      2837     350 2017-08-29 2018-02-27 182 days          3    2017-12-07  2018-01-26          50 days
> 310:      2837     350 2017-08-29 2018-02-27 182 days          4    2018-01-26  2018-02-27          32 days
> 311:      2838     364 2017-11-26 2018-02-27  93 days          1    2017-11-26  2018-01-15          50 days
> 312:      2838     364 2017-11-26 2018-02-27  93 days          2    2018-01-15  2018-02-27          43 days
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution. Notice that I converted the `duration` column to integer for the operation. You can convert it back if you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
# Define the number of days for one duration
num <- 7L

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(duration = as.integer(duration)) %>%
  # Count number of duration and how many days left
  mutate(times = duration %/% num, left = duration %% num) %>%
  # Repeat each row based on number of duration
  slice(rep(row_number(), times = times + 1)) %>%
  group_by(sample_id, site_id) %>%
  # Process the start and end date
  mutate(seg_start_date = if_else(row_number() < n(),
                              start_date + days(num * (n() - 1)),
                              end_date - days(left)),
         seg_end_date = if_else(row_number() < n(),
                            seg_start_date + days(num - 1),
                            end_date)) %>%
  # Create segment id 
  mutate(segment_id = 1:n()) %>%
  # Create segment duration
  mutate(seg_duration = ifelse(row_number() == n(), left, num)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-times, -left)

head(dat2) %>% as.data.frame()
#   sample_id site_id start_date   end_date duration seg_start_date seg_end_date segment_id seg_duration
# 1         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14       32     2015-04-12   2015-04-18          1            7
# 2         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14       32     2015-04-19   2015-04-25          2            7
# 3         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14       32     2015-04-26   2015-05-02          3            7
# 4         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14       32     2015-05-03   2015-05-09          4            7
# 5         2       2 2015-04-12 2015-05-14       32     2015-05-10   2015-05-14          5            4
# 6         8      13 2015-06-10 2015-06-18        8     2015-06-10   2015-06-16          1            7
```

Comment: Thanks @www! I just tried this but it failed at `mutate(duration = as.integer(duration))` with the error "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'integer'." What does that mean? BTW, what do the operators `%/%` and `%%` mean?

Comment: See my other comment, but after lots of trying I discovered that all I have to do is rename() the columns in the data frame to some other names, then rename() them back, afterwards your code runs fine! (don't suppose you know why???) Anyway, what do the operators %/% and %% mean? I think that's the main thing preventing me from fully understanding what your code means. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! That reference is very helpful. I also just noticed that this code creates "extra" segments where the duration is 0 days which I don't need, but they are fairly easy to `filter()` out afterwards.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I restarted from a clean R session, and running everything by directly using the `dput()` output in my original post and your code, but the `seg_start_date` and `seg_end_date` columns are the same for each row where `seg_duration == 7`. For example, for `sample_id == 2` & `site_id == 2`, those two dates are 2015-05-10 and 2015-05-16 for all rows except the last one. Any idea why this might be? Thanks!