# Joining data frames by lubridate date %within% intervals

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join, lubridate

I've been practicing and learning wrangling R data frames with columns that contain `lubridate` data types, such as an example problem in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407177/r-lubridate-split-durations-into-sub-durations/51408106?noredirect=1#comment89796193_51408106).

Now, I am trying to do the equivalent of joining two data frames, but joining them by whether one timestamp in one data frame falls within an `interval` in the other data frame. For example:

This is `df1`:

```
> glimpse(df1)
Observations: 6,160
Variables: 4
$ upload_id  <int> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, ...
$ site_id    <int> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, ...
$ segment_id <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
$ interval   <S4: Interval> 2015-04-12 UTC--2015-04-19 UTC, 2015-04-19 UTC--201...
```

Where there is a bunch of `lubridate` time intervals each with a corresponding *unique* combination of `upload_id`, `site_id`, and `segment_id`.

And this is `df2`:

```
> glimpse(df2)
Observations: 32,385
Variables: 3
$ sequence_id <int> 2047, 2067, 2069, 2072, 2075, 2081, 2086, 2091, 2096, 2104,...
$ upload_id   <int> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5,...
$ taken       <dttm> 2015-04-11 23:09:59, 2015-04-15 19:17:10, 2015-04-16 07:42...
```

Where there is a series of timestamps in column `taken` with corresponding *unique* combinations of `sequence_id` and `upload_id`.

Essentially, I want to `left_join(df2, df1)` where the needed `by` argument considers two things: (1) the shared `upload_id` column; and (2) whether `taken` in `df2` falls within `interval` in `df1`. This is because for any given `taken`, it might fall `%within%` multiple `interval`s, and vice versa, so I want to use `upload_id` as a unique identifier for each `taken` so that each `taken` in `df2` will be matched to only one other row in `df1`. After the join operation, I expect the new data frame to have six columns: `sequence_id`, `taken`, `upload_id`, `site_id`, `segment_id`, and `interval`. How can this be done tidyly?

**EDIT:** A comment suggested that uploading .Rdata files may be untrustworthy and another stated that it's against the policy here. So I removed the .Rdata files, and I tried to take a 300-row subset of each data frame via `dput()`, here is `df1`:

```
structure(list(upload_id = c(1050L, 1582L, 2336L, 2665L, 1007L, 
2148L, 275L, 2738L, 1501L, 64L, 2737L, 1547L, 2146L, 2596L, 457L, 
2141L, 2790L, 362L, 2835L, 2741L, 575L, 914L, 2820L, 2572L, 2791L, 
2157L, 1117L, 1535L, 2738L, 794L, 1335L, 2737L, 2570L, 1597L, 
300L, 460L, 1701L, 2142L, 274L, 339L, 2109L, 500L, 2184L, 2837L, 
1238L, 2837L, 2727L, 1175L, 1524L, 303L, 1714L, 1412L, 1894L, 
340L, 1495L, 869L, 995L, 2438L, 1974L, 2762L, 205L, 1581L, 1527L, 
2818L, 1617L, 2537L, 1956L, 638L, 1808L, 2151L, 771L, 2709L, 
2185L, 2015L, 2511L, 1163L, 2557L, 1377L, 2213L, 2560L, 1417L, 
1934L, 1860L, 2772L, 2614L, 2698L, 421L, 2609L, 1418L, 2355L, 
463L, 2697L, 347L, 1531L, 1427L, 2548L, 2218L, 2781L, 1962L, 
396L, 234L, 2846L, 4L, 2742L, 2838L, 1676L, 1635L, 2810L, 1990L, 
2514L, 2809L, 1354L, 2668L, 2737L, 1606L, 764L, 1176L, 1442L, 
519L, 2584L, 1021L, 352L, 2314L, 2662L, 1368L, 1043L, 2207L, 
2792L, 684L, 1806L, 2743L, 2557L, 1971L, 1510L, 418L, 1866L, 
1569L, 1717L, 1992L, 1629L, 2189L, 316L, 2030L, 2840L, 2307L, 
1506L, 1962L, 1249L, 2791L, 670L, 592L, 236L, 2781L, 793L, 2790L, 
2640L, 2517L, 855L, 626L, 1303L, 2241L, 1541L, 910L, 155L, 1617L, 
29L, 916L, 732L, 2006L, 2742L, 2788L, 2830L, 2664L, 1455L, 1062L, 
937L, 1543L, 781L, 737L, 901L, 2633L, 194L, 1000L, 1170L, 1567L, 
2826L, 73L, 801L, 970L, 1327L, 2688L, 1538L, 2306L, 2170L, 1977L, 
2367L, 186L, 1990L, 2606L, 2000L, 2818L, 396L, 696L, 630L, 2835L, 
2067L, 1540L, 51L, 511L, 2587L, 2737L, 1961L, 594L, 1867L, 1042L, 
116L, 1532L, 760L, 2662L, 2814L, 2585L, 2596L, 2837L, 1870L, 
1971L, 73L, 2595L, 1955L, 692L, 2062L, 2742L, 2084L, 1098L, 2205L, 
1404L, 2627L, 809L, 2684L, 2570L, 322L, 2605L, 2016L, 2782L, 
54L, 2254L, 1165L, 655L, 532L, 732L, 534L, 2664L, 1880L, 1444L, 
1920L, 477L, 2728L, 2640L, 1434L, 100L, 2587L, 1545L, 250L, 282L, 
1756L, 940L, 2826L, 1005L, 2835L, 2152L, 203L, 1970L, 579L, 1234L, 
2682L, 1050L, 2594L, 199L, 945L, 758L, 1262L, 796L, 2156L, 921L, 
1961L, 817L, 486L, 982L, 394L, 1928L, 2237L, 2570L, 2144L, 2386L, 
325L, 2729L, 2685L, 901L, 2042L, 141L, 2248L), site_id = c(184L, 
278L, 73L, 364L, 231L, 244L, 72L, 364L, 74L, 52L, 350L, 248L, 
223L, 306L, 117L, 223L, 350L, 115L, 357L, 295L, 113L, 74L, 350L, 
348L, 364L, 267L, 74L, 248L, 364L, 198L, 73L, 350L, 347L, 260L, 
103L, 134L, 271L, 223L, 72L, 120L, 73L, 145L, 214L, 350L, 74L, 
350L, 361L, 227L, 160L, 73L, 73L, 237L, 292L, 110L, 267L, 205L, 
230L, 74L, 306L, 295L, 47L, 261L, 44L, 357L, 280L, 355L, 199L, 
119L, 160L, 73L, 186L, 348L, 214L, 295L, 348L, 160L, 306L, 74L, 
191L, 350L, 73L, 191L, 191L, 364L, 306L, 364L, 74L, 73L, 74L, 
74L, 155L, 350L, 54L, 248L, 260L, 114L, 241L, 360L, 292L, 31L, 
36L, 73L, 7L, 360L, 364L, 74L, 262L, 361L, 292L, 350L, 360L, 
256L, 73L, 350L, 280L, 184L, 44L, 258L, 146L, 347L, 217L, 44L, 
113L, 357L, 191L, 233L, 245L, 360L, 156L, 293L, 360L, 306L, 292L, 
226L, 74L, 36L, 73L, 73L, 199L, 244L, 241L, 110L, 295L, 361L, 
248L, 251L, 292L, 113L, 364L, 74L, 160L, 105L, 360L, 202L, 350L, 
306L, 351L, 201L, 160L, 247L, 320L, 248L, 213L, 54L, 280L, 41L, 
198L, 187L, 74L, 360L, 357L, 287L, 350L, 44L, 234L, 105L, 248L, 
200L, 174L, 198L, 73L, 54L, 217L, 236L, 277L, 361L, 63L, 194L, 
160L, 73L, 361L, 248L, 320L, 74L, 293L, 73L, 68L, 292L, 350L, 
199L, 357L, 31L, 166L, 165L, 357L, 312L, 248L, 42L, 148L, 350L, 
350L, 147L, 116L, 248L, 174L, 47L, 226L, 74L, 357L, 73L, 348L, 
306L, 350L, 293L, 292L, 63L, 348L, 298L, 174L, 316L, 360L, 312L, 
227L, 319L, 237L, 350L, 160L, 348L, 347L, 108L, 306L, 293L, 361L, 
54L, 74L, 74L, 73L, 56L, 187L, 74L, 350L, 199L, 74L, 271L, 56L, 
360L, 306L, 226L, 72L, 350L, 248L, 90L, 91L, 74L, 44L, 361L, 
217L, 357L, 73L, 55L, 191L, 73L, 226L, 347L, 184L, 357L, 95L, 
218L, 196L, 249L, 197L, 74L, 74L, 147L, 199L, 145L, 217L, 136L, 
295L, 73L, 347L, 223L, 113L, 47L, 350L, 350L, 198L, 310L, 23L, 
74L), segment_id = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 11L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
7L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 15L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 23L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 18L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 15L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 16L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), interval = new("Interval", .Data = c(604800, 86400, 86400, 
259200, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 86400, 86400, 604800, 
604800, 518400, 604800, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
518400, 604800, 86400, 604800, 604800, 259200, 604800, 86400, 
604800, 604800, 518400, 172800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 
432000, 604800, 604800, 259200, 432000, 86400, 604800, 432000, 
604800, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 86400, 86400, 
604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 345600, 518400, 
604800, 345600, 604800, 86400, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 86400, 86400, 604800, 518400, 604800, 604800, 
86400, 604800, 86400, 86400, 604800, 604800, 432000, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 604800, 86400, 86400, 259200, 86400, 604800, 
604800, 259200, 604800, 604800, 604800, 259200, 604800, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 432000, 604800, 604800, 86400, 604800, 604800, 
518400, 518400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 604800, 
86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 86400, 518400, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 518400, 518400, 604800, 86400, 86400, 172800, 
604800, 604800, 259200, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 432000, 
604800, 604800, 86400, 604800, 432000, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 86400, 518400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
518400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 86400, 
604800, 604800, 604800, 345600, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
604800, 86400, 86400, 345600, 172800, 172800, 604800, 604800, 
518400, 604800, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 
86400, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 432000, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 345600, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 172800, 86400, 604800, 
86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 86400, 518400, 259200, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
604800, 432000, 604800, 604800, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
259200, 86400, 86400, 86400, 518400, 86400, 86400, 604800, 604800, 
259200, 345600, 604800, 604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 
604800, 259200, 604800, 86400, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 
86400, 172800, 604800, 86400, 604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 
432000, 604800, 518400, 345600, 518400, 86400, 86400, 604800, 
604800, 604800, 604800, 172800, 604800, 86400, 604800, 518400, 
86400, 604800, 604800, 518400, 172800, 259200, 86400, 86400), 
    start = structure(c(1463097600, 1479081600, 1499817600, 1511654400, 
    1464912000, 1493337600, 1440028800, 1514073600, 1478995200, 
    1438128000, 1507593600, 1475193600, 1491782400, 1507593600, 
    1445212800, 1487462400, 1505174400, 1445731200, 1519084800, 
    1515456000, 1449964800, 1463529600, 1508198400, 1504483200, 
    1517702400, 1485648000, 1468195200, 1476403200, 1514678400, 
    1460073600, 1472860800, 1508198400, 1504483200, 1475798400, 
    1444348800, 1451692800, 1481587200, 1488153600, 1439769600, 
    1445126400, 1492732800, 1449446400, 1494201600, 1513641600, 
    1470441600, 1505174400, 1510704000, 1469145600, 1478563200, 
    1444780800, 1483228800, 1475280000, 1485129600, 1444867200, 
    1477267200, 1462492800, 1464652800, 1503532800, 1488931200, 
    1516060800, 1441584000, 1475884800, 1479772800, 1519084800, 
    1478908800, 1505952000, 1486598400, 1444608000, 1485216000, 
    1493942400, 1459814400, 1505088000, 1494201600, 1488240000, 
    1504483200, 1469491200, 1506384000, 1474502400, 1495411200, 
    1506384000, 1475366400, 1487548800, 1485734400, 1512259200, 
    1505779200, 1512864000, 1448496000, 1509494400, 1475884800, 
    1500422400, 1448582400, 1511222400, 1444348800, 1474416000, 
    1475193600, 1506038400, 1495411200, 1513036800, 1487548800, 
    1439856000, 1441497600, 1519948800, 1428192000, 1513641600, 
    1517097600, 1481673600, 1475884800, 1508889600, 1488758400, 
    1505779200, 1510617600, 1471305600, 1511913600, 1508803200, 
    1477094400, 1457481600, 1469577600, 1473206400, 1449187200, 
    1505692800, 1465776000, 1444694400, 1497744000, 1511827200, 
    1473465600, 1465516800, 1494892800, 1515456000, 1454803200, 
    1485216000, 1511827200, 1505779200, 1485129600, 1478649600, 
    1447977600, 1465516800, 1479945600, 1483315200, 1489622400, 
    1479340800, 1494201600, 1444867200, 1488844800, 1517356800, 
    1495756800, 1477785600, 1488758400, 1468800000, 1514678400, 
    1455753600, 1452556800, 1442534400, 1514246400, 1456617600, 
    1517270400, 1505779200, 1505606400, 1462147200, 1453852800, 
    1471824000, 1495584000, 1477008000, 1462579200, 1439596800, 
    1478304000, 1433808000, 1462492800, 1457395200, 1489881600, 
    1513036800, 1517875200, 1518912000, 1510617600, 1476230400, 
    1466121600, 1463443200, 1475193600, 1458432000, 1457395200, 
    1460678400, 1510617600, 1441324800, 1465171200, 1469491200, 
    1477872000, 1511913600, 1439510400, 1460332800, 1464134400, 
    1472774400, 1508889600, 1476403200, 1494979200, 1494460800, 
    1485820800, 1501027200, 1441324800, 1487548800, 1506384000, 
    1489017600, 1517270400, 1447113600, 1455580800, 1453680000, 
    1516060800, 1491264000, 1475193600, 1437696000, 1449446400, 
    1503964800, 1514246400, 1487030400, 1452124800, 1485216000, 
    1464825600, 1438905600, 1479772800, 1459641600, 1506988800, 
    1518739200, 1508112000, 1506988800, 1504569600, 1485216000, 
    1488153600, 1437696000, 1503878400, 1487808000, 1455321600, 
    1489881600, 1515456000, 1491609600, 1466121600, 1494201600, 
    1471651200, 1509408000, 1460592000, 1512345600, 1505692800, 
    1445040000, 1505174400, 1487030400, 1515542400, 1437868800, 
    1496620800, 1469577600, 1455235200, 1450224000, 1.458e+09, 
    1450828800, 1510012800, 1485388800, 1476835200, 1487894400, 
    1447977600, 1510617600, 1507593600, 1474934400, 1438905600, 
    1504569600, 1477008000, 1443312000, 1443312000, 1484524800, 
    1464048000, 1517961600, 1463356800, 1517270400, 1494028800, 
    1441238400, 1488758400, 1452643200, 1470700800, 1511740800, 
    1461888000, 1508803200, 1441238400, 1463616000, 1455062400, 
    1471478400, 1460073600, 1494115200, 1463616000, 1488240000, 
    1460073600, 1448236800, 1463961600, 1447372800, 1485820800, 
    1496102400, 1507507200, 1489968000, 1499126400, 1444176000, 
    1504569600, 1512432000, 1463097600, 1490745600, 1440028800, 
    1496448000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is `df2`:

```
structure(list(sequence_id = c(10545297L, 5696697L, 26853675L, 
26800598L, 5477912L, 3564676L, 11545989L, 26788357L, 26790778L, 
4682984L, 12887744L, 4254651L, 6472328L, 18236650L, 26829066L, 
26784117L, 26886686L, 797197L, 26820954L, 26791541L, 11657412L, 
3960964L, 10189029L, 21286407L, 12914356L, 26793531L, 26802965L, 
12435451L, 5484298L, 26827162L, 26853752L, 25711869L, 9030699L, 
14386264L, 26802894L, 26377583L, 13291447L, 1851672L, 26790782L, 
9900386L, 26797667L, 6561255L, 26818879L, 11648069L, 14259988L, 
26809952L, 26809264L, 15071783L, 26791374L, 26853008L, 6762100L, 
26853620L, 26880265L, 26878102L, 26809279L, 26787754L, 5502014L, 
17810813L, 18236753L, 5568166L, 9252741L, 26786093L, 18418962L, 
1218679L, 26801395L, 16954415L, 26853619L, 26800113L, 26817488L, 
26811724L, 26809375L, 26809666L, 5869152L, 7681085L, 26894216L, 
15810230L, 26829083L, 26817434L, 26789887L, 26785533L, 26796803L, 
26786930L, 26825007L, 26784040L, 26810066L, 26853657L, 18236660L, 
26797322L, 26825026L, 4103811L, 26878149L, 10545137L, 26784075L, 
26902434L, 3948950L, 26816568L, 11453844L, 26826969L, 26813846L, 
26897750L, 26802715L, 26790888L, 26815971L, 26797683L, 4726015L, 
4617411L, 26797067L, 9252726L, 26797067L, 26785670L, 26789320L, 
26901211L, 26894241L, 499985L, 26825082L, 21774171L, 26803324L, 
26815122L, 56056L, 18236919L, 5425808L, 13209778L, 4726052L, 
14386262L, 5477952L, 5564830L, 9756473L, 26894173L, 7136912L, 
26792378L, 26878986L, 7726907L, 26903079L, 9517618L, 10730383L, 
21774142L, 26901299L, 15071807L, 26786514L, 26901389L, 26903784L, 
26802651L, 7817686L, 26805379L, 4617432L, 21624158L, 9656749L, 
26789389L, 25399602L, 26901650L, 26797702L, 9900332L, 10965877L, 
15268795L, 26896376L, 26787716L, 26851798L, 15810222L, 12887738L, 
26827055L, 16102402L, 26796994L, 26784422L, 14725739L, 26901257L, 
26853712L, 26785221L, 26793075L, 11658007L, 26823570L, 26791524L, 
26797467L, 26796972L, 8501567L, 26799777L, 5572466L, 26787249L, 
18385461L, 4791179L, 15810380L, 26808430L, 10239023L, 26790569L, 
26805358L, 18158022L, 15810244L, 26878116L, 10623114L, 267502L, 
9517623L, 16102411L, 26377567L, 8230310L, 13076594L, 26878082L, 
415271L, 13833529L, 26823199L, 2410L, 26900200L), upload_id = c(851L, 
592L, 2314L, 1799L, 546L, 357L, 925L, 299L, 1611L, 465L, 976L, 
424L, 641L, 1249L, 2274L, 1436L, 2556L, 157L, 2166L, 1666L, 928L, 
388L, 836L, 1405L, 977L, 1698L, 1928L, 961L, 547L, 2261L, 2316L, 
1486L, 774L, 1038L, 1920L, 1503L, 993L, 229L, 1611L, 819L, 1767L, 
651L, 2151L, 927L, 1034L, 2049L, 2028L, 1074L, 1629L, 2302L, 
666L, 2314L, 2434L, 2387L, 2028L, 392L, 557L, 1217L, 1249L, 564L, 
783L, 883L, 1265L, 179L, 1846L, 1159L, 2314L, 1783L, 2138L, 2079L, 
2035L, 2045L, 594L, 736L, 2569L, 1102L, 2277L, 2089L, 52L, 1025L, 
1746L, 669L, 2230L, 1506L, 2055L, 2314L, 1249L, 1757L, 2230L, 
406L, 2387L, 851L, 1506L, 2787L, 385L, 2128L, 922L, 2251L, 2102L, 
2711L, 1907L, 1605L, 2125L, 1767L, 459L, 458L, 1746L, 783L, 1746L, 
1000L, 98L, 2750L, 2569L, 122L, 2230L, 1416L, 1929L, 2110L, 41L, 
1249L, 542L, 985L, 459L, 1038L, 546L, 563L, 815L, 2569L, 681L, 
1665L, 2419L, 738L, 2821L, 792L, 879L, 1416L, 2751L, 1074L, 779L, 
2755L, 2849L, 1904L, 740L, 1951L, 458L, 1399L, 810L, 98L, 1479L, 
2760L, 1767L, 819L, 891L, 1086L, 2693L, 440L, 2292L, 1102L, 976L, 
2257L, 1106L, 1746L, 1442L, 1055L, 2751L, 2314L, 1400L, 1680L, 
929L, 2194L, 1661L, 1765L, 1746L, 769L, 1774L, 570L, 572L, 1264L, 
473L, 1102L, 2009L, 838L, 1586L, 1951L, 1235L, 1102L, 2387L, 
864L, 95L, 792L, 1106L, 1503L, 762L, 984L, 2387L, 120L, 1012L, 
1681L, 5L, 2722L), taken = structure(c(1461607098, 1357440699, 
1497946386, 1480535568, 1450529748, 1446385695, 1463741872, 1444334424, 
1479280400, 1449136788, 1462488333, 1448183687, 1454753449, 1467598406, 
1497333513, 1475588136, 1507455271, 1440251873, 1494085620, 1481115392, 
1463814473, 1441262063, 1461931738, 1471111946, 1462814426, 1482484495, 
1488369500, 1463341759, 1451394079, 1496897690, 1499171773, 1478337380, 
1459646439, 1465542945, 1487492476, 1478507314, 1465151499, 1440878596, 
1479297148, 1461237979, 1484471493, 1455032917, 1493960869, 1462284996, 
1465967563, 1490769440, 1490547948, 1458713033, 1480133603, 1498456304, 
1454837375, 1497347897, 1502541854, 1499517904, 1490563199, 1443806209, 
1451728803, 1469188230, 1468317942, 1452000085, 1459446443, 1462629579, 
1469694294, 1438787731, 1486631809, 1469203046, 1497347627, 1485346076, 
1493760152, 1491737060, 1490640549, 1490971607, 1452390124, 1458148243, 
1506439827, 1465194751, 1497427230, 1493546423, 1437499385, 1465909309, 
1479587401, 1455275863, 1494462120, 1475150180, 1486585139, 1497692625, 
1467632404, 1483992126, 1494818410, 1443259589, 1499966514, 1461252282, 
1476463125, 1517825105, 1439276459, 1492732155, 1463060151, 1496495881, 
1492443646, 1513698078, 1487699018, 1478033857, 1493459209, 1484574255, 
1445463014, 1445377602, 1482270132, 1459068085, 1482270132, 1465324190, 
1437645893, 1516448011, 1506768001, 1439499230, 1495154336, 1475995917, 
1487326465, 1492842646, 1437512735, 1471084135, 1451331488, 1464596049, 
1445487433, 1465542768, 1450654515, 1450251138, 1458756627, 1505539318, 
1456158745, 1481191991, 1502958079, 1456851898, 1519301621, 1460132323, 
1462246721, 1475745018, 1516537759, 1459318655, 1460122320, 1514916703, 
1520412137, 1488024066, 1458195162, 1487453288, 1445389049, 1474006970, 
1459754632, 1438269539, 1477661255, 1516007192, 1484753445, 1461136855, 
1463031275, 1466667291, 1509613313, 1441042946, 1497589967, 1465033581, 
1462417047, 1496682390, 1467178192, 1481293492, 1469788770, 1462814225, 
1516529474, 1498386350, 1470051133, 1481928052, 1463302826, 1495262048, 
1480681123, 1483683739, 1481041639, 1459773430, 1484652813, 1451208417, 
1451471584, 1467788032, 1445564488, 1466521584, 1490178592, 1461418924, 
1478867863, 1486761277, 1470424975, 1465375208, 1499603574, 1462529520, 
1438348434, 1460184847, 1467258314, 1478446800, 1457830628, 1464092571, 
1499339617, 1439448916, 1465530027, 1491299676, 1431043226, 1511424274
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The problem with these subsets is that I'm not sure how much overlap remains between the two of them for the join, but hopefully there will be some. I tried to `filter()` one to include `upload_id`s from the other, but I get an error saying:

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) :    Column `interval` classes Period
>   and Interval from lubridate are currently not supported.

Sorry this sounds complicated, please let me know if I can clarify this question further. I am truly grateful for your help!

Comment: I see that you uploaded the data with cloud links. An understandable idea, but long against Meta policy for security reasons and also it's not really in the spirit of the MCVE (where the M is *Minimal*). Much better to create a minimal, complete, verifiable (runnable) example.

Comment: Eww. Rdata files to download? What makes us trust you? Better would be to leave text files of R `dput` operations. That way we could examine them for malicious content.

Comment: @Hack-R, @42: I have removed the .Rdata files and replaced them with `dput()` outputs from a 300-row subset of the original data. Please let me know if the question is now up to spec, I humbly apologise for offending you as I truly did not know there is a rule against uploading .Rdata files. Please forgive me for this intrusion. Can you let me know if the question is more answerable now? Thank you so much for your kind understanding and help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fuzzyjoin` package:

```
library(BiocManager)
library(lubridate)
library(fuzzyjoin)
colnames(df2) <- c("sequence_id", "upload_id",  "start") 
df1$start <- int_start(df1$interval)
df1$end <- int_end(df1$interval)
df2$end <- df2$start

df3 <- interval_inner_join(df1, df2, by=c("start", "end"))   # let 1 join with 2
```