# Match columns in R based on date within one day

Tags: r, date, match, lubridate

I have two tables. The first table contains my reference measurements:

```
> test
        date site value product
A1 2017-06-10    A   0.6  meter1
A2 2017-06-10    B   0.5  meter1
A3 2017-06-11    C   0.5  meter1
A4 2017-06-18    A   0.1  meter1
A5 2017-06-19    B   0.6  meter1
A6 2017-06-19    C   0.6  meter1
```

The second table contains a second set of measurements from different instruments that were taken on other dates that may or may not match.

```
> test2
         date site value product
B1 2017-06-07    A   0.4  meter2
B2 2017-06-09    B   0.5  meter2
B3 2017-06-09    C   0.6  meter3
B4 2017-06-09    A   0.2  meter2
B5 2017-06-20    B   0.7  meter3
B6 2017-06-23    B   0.5  meter2
```

I want to identify the measurements that match the first table within a certain time interval, for example within 1 day. Which should give something like this:

```
>   test3
        date site value product match
1 2017-06-07    A   0.4  meter2    NA
2 2017-06-09    B   0.5  meter2    A2
3 2017-06-09    C   0.6  meter3    NA
4 2017-06-09    A   0.2  meter2    A1
5 2017-06-20    B   0.7  meter3    A5
6 2017-06-23    B   0.5  meter2    NA
```

On top of that, I would like to plot each of these measurements against the reference measurements in ggplot.

I tried different ways with lubridate, but couldn't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
  test <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17327, 17327, 17328, 17335,17336, 17336),
                                  class = "Date"),
                 site = c("A", "B", "C", "A","B", "C"),
                 value = c(0.6, 0.5,0.5, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6),
                 product = c("meter1", "meter1", "meter1", "meter1", "meter1", "meter1"))
            , row.names = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6"),
            class = "data.frame")



  test2 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17324, 17326, 17326, 17326,17337, 17340),
                                          class = "Date"),
                         site = c("A", "B", "C", "A","B", "B"),
                         value = c(0.4, 0.5,0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5),
                         product = c("meter2", "meter2", "meter3", "meter2", "meter3", "meter2"))
                    , row.names = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6"),
                    class = "data.frame")

  test3 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17324, 17326, 17326, 17326,17337, 17340),
                                           class = "Date"),
                          site = c("A", "B", "C", "A","B", "B"),
                          value = c(0.4, 0.5,0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5),
                          product = c("meter2", "meter2", "meter3", "meter2", "meter3", "meter2"),
                          match = c("NA", "A2", "NA", "A1", "A5", "NA")),
                     row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                     class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following solution inspired by Benedicts hint on fuzzyjoin:

```
temp <- test %>% mutate(dateStart = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y") - days(1)) %>%
  mutate(dateEnd = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y") + days(1))

temp
library(fuzzyjoin)
temp2 <- fuzzy_inner_join(
  test2, temp,
  by = c(
    "site"="site",
    "date" = "dateStart",
    "date" = "dateEnd"),
  match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))
temp2
> temp2
      date.x site.x value.x product.x     date.y site.y value.y product.y  dateStart    dateEnd
1 2017-06-09      B     0.5    meter2 2017-06-10      B     0.5    meter1 2017-06-09 2017-06-11
2 2017-06-09      A     0.2    meter2 2017-06-10      A     0.6    meter1 2017-06-09 2017-06-11
3 2017-06-20      B     0.7    meter3 2017-06-19      B     0.6    meter1 2017-06-18 2017-06-20
```

This can then easily be plotted using:

```
ggplot(temp2, aes(value.x, value.y)) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this SO question, yours might be a possible duplicate: [Joining data frames by lubridate date %within% intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412533/joining-data-frames-by-lubridate-date-within-intervals).

Seems to me that the package {[fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin)} or {[lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/)}'s `%within%` might help.

There's another example in greater detail here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881.

> On top of that, I would like to plot each of these measurements
>   against the reference measurements in ggplot.

That should be easy when you're wrangling your data in a long format and use a group in {ggplot}.

Comment: These are all suggestions and don't answer OP's question with exact code. You should add this as a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks,  fuzzyjoin did the trick. I used it in my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is with a rolling join from `data.table` with `roll = "nearest"`. Note that *only* the final argument in `on =` will be a rolling join.

One common stumbling block is that `data.table` combines the column that is joined on, so you need to make a copy of it first.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test); setDT(test2)
test[,date1 := date]
test2[,date2 := date]
test2[test,on = c("site","date"), roll = "nearest"][,diff := abs(date2-date1)][diff <= 1,]
         date site value product      date2 i.value i.product      date1   diff
1: 2017-06-10    A   0.2  meter2 2017-06-09     0.6    meter1 2017-06-10 1 days
2: 2017-06-10    B   0.5  meter2 2017-06-09     0.5    meter1 2017-06-10 1 days
3: 2017-06-19    B   0.7  meter3 2017-06-20     0.6    meter1 2017-06-19 1 days
```

This gives you all the combinations of rows of `test` and `test2` that are within 1 day of each other. From there you could `merge` back onto `test` or do whatever other steps you want.

```
matches <- test2[test,on = c("site","date"), roll = "nearest"][,diff := abs(date2-date1)][diff <= 1,]
merge(test,matches[,.(date,site,product,value,date2)],by = c("date", "site"),all.x = TRUE)
         date site value.x product.x      date1 product.y value.y      date2
1: 2017-06-10    A     0.6    meter1 2017-06-10    meter2     0.2 2017-06-09
2: 2017-06-10    B     0.5    meter1 2017-06-10    meter2     0.5 2017-06-09
3: 2017-06-11    C     0.5    meter1 2017-06-11      <NA>      NA       <NA>
4: 2017-06-18    A     0.1    meter1 2017-06-18      <NA>      NA       <NA>
5: 2017-06-19    B     0.6    meter1 2017-06-19    meter3     0.7 2017-06-20
6: 2017-06-19    C     0.6    meter1 2017-06-19      <NA>      NA       <NA>
```

Comment: That is a nice solution. also that it gives the difference in days.